# Issuue while implementing onClickListener

Tags: android, view

See this simple code,But i am getting Description
**The method onClick(View) of type CheckboxActivity must override a superclass method   CheckboxActivity.java** on my onClick(View v) method.

```
public class CheckboxActivity extends Activity implements Button.OnClickListener{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        Button b1;
        CheckBox c1, c2;
        EditText et1;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            et1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            c1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);
            c2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check2);
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override 
           public void onClick(View v){
            et1.setText("");
            if (c1.isChecked())
            et1.setText("Android ");
            if (c2.isChecked())
            et1.setText(et1.getText()+"iPhone ");
        }
    }

Anyone please help
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public class CheckboxActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Comment: You have to import OnClickListener of any widget or View first.Is not it ?.I import did as u told but facing same problem.

Comment: @Android Killer The import for the `OnClickListener` interface is `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: yes i already did that buddy.Still getting same problem.If i am removing @Override from onClick(View v), then it is working fine.Any idea?

Comment: @Android Killer ,`@Override` means you are overriding a method from the super class and `Activity` doesn't have a `onClick` method. In your case you implement the `OnClickListener` which is an interface and you don't use `@Override`, you just implement the methods from that interface.

Answer (score 1):

You delete your onClick() first.
Then change ur first line as

```
public class CheckboxActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

and the import should be

```
android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Then after your onCreate() do a `right click -> Source -> Override/Implemented Methods`

the onClick() will be automatically selected in the dialog box. Click ok and type in ur required things into the method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sources of Activity and don't have working environment to write code and run javac, so I'm just guessing, please check yourself:

1. Activity has onClick method already - make anonymous OnClickListener
   instance and pass it to the button (or remove inheritance from
   Button.OnClickListener and don't forget to call super when view is
   not your button). Could be also that contract has different access
   level in activity.
2. Level of language is 1.5 and you can't use annotation @override for interfaces.